# Java: Type safety : A generic array of A is created for a varargs parameter

Tags: java, casting, variadic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to solve the “A generic array of T is created for a varargs parameter” compiler warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445233/is-it-possible-to-solve-the-a-generic-array-of-t-is-created-for-a-varargs-param)

Consider this is given:

```
interface A<T> { /*...*/ }
interface B<T> extends A<T> { /*...*/ }
class C { /*...*/ }
void foo(A<T>... a) { /*...*/ }
```

Now, some other code wants to use `foo`:

```
B<C> b1 /* = ... */;
B<C> b2 /* = ... */;
foo(b1, b2);
```

This gives me the warning

```
Type safety : A generic array of A is created for a varargs parameter
```

So I changed the call to this:

```
foo((A<C>) b1, (A<C>) b2);
```

This still gives me the same warning.

Why? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you can really do is suppress that warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Java 7 will eliminate that warning for client code, moving it to the declaration of `foo(A... a)` rather than the call site. See the Project Coin proposal [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000217.html).

Comment: The mentioned Project Coin feature is now available - see [@SafeVarargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html) in Java 7.

Answer (score 5):

*Edit: Answer updated to reflect that question was updated to show A is indeed generic.*

*<strike>I would think that A must be a generic to get that error.  Is A a generic in your project, but the code sample above leaves the generic decl out?</strike>*

*<strike>If so,</strike> Because A is generic,*  you can't work around warning cleanly.  Varargs are implemented using an array and an array doesn't support generic arrays as explained here:

[Java generics and varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096708/java-generics-and-varargs)

Comment: Yea it is. I guess I simplified the example too much. Will change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<T> void foo(T... a) { /*...*/ }
```