# What is the most correct way to pass several parameters of different types to doInBackground (Params... params) method?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I' m designing Android client for a web site. So there are a lot of different network operations i have to implement. For a example user authorization or searching on a server. To do this I must send JSON request to REST web server with some parameters and URL. So I must pass not only String parameters but some data structure (LinkedHashMap for instance). The problem i don't know the most correct way. By far I did next:

1. `protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... param)`. And then convert param[0],param [1] to different type. I think it is a bad way.
2. Using javatuples library for this purpose:

`protected Void doInBackground(Pair<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>... params)`

It seems too complex and redundant code. And the most important I must add

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

or  I got a type safety warning.

So may be some experts can help me with this and advice the most correct and efficient way.

Comment: Make different `AsyncTask` implementations for different types or do it via a class hierarchy where you just operate on a common base-class / interface that is always the same for all types. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096708/java-generics-and-varargs for the warning

Comment: Why not build your own class, say MyServerRequest, and then just pass an instance of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have your own constructor for the Asynctask and store these as fields which you could use in doinBackground

```
    private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Task(int a, long b){
       //store a, b
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {    
    }   
  }
```

and then

```
new Task(1,2).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

"If i were you"  i wont use `AsyncTask` for my `REST Application` instead you can come up with other Design Patterns which take over the AsyncTask job. 
one of the reasons is lost `bandwidth` may occur how ?? if you are in the middle of `Http Transaction`  perhaps posting or getting data , a phone call my come and your activity will be in the background and the OS may kill your lovely activity and shutdown the `AsyncTask` .

you can use the `Service` component instead of `AsyncTask` since android rate it more highly than Activities in the background .

take a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) old video from Google IO by virgil

Answer (score -1):

I typically make a simple class to encapsulate all the data I'll be using.