# Android AsyncTask, warning: "Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter"

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How do I get rid of the warning? The code I'm using:

```
private void tryNew(List<Something> somethingList){
    new AsyncTask<List<Something>,Void,Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<Something> [] somethingList) {
            //some code
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(somethingList);
}
```

Comment: Wrap `List<Something>` in an object that isn't generic like `class Foo { public List<Something> list; }` and use `AsyncTask<Foo, ...` - that resolves it - or simply ignore it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096708/java-generics-and-varargs has some details about it - and if you target 19+ you could try adding `@SafeVarargs` to the `doInBackground` method

Comment: Late addition, but worth noting that while adding `@SafeVarargs` to `doInBackground` is possible (and can help to eliminate an associated warning message - `Possible heap pollution from paramaterized vararg type`), it _does not_ remove the original "unchecked generics" warning, because you don't call `doInBackground` directly. You use `new AsyncTask(...).execute()`.

Answer (score 4):

I was with this same warning and could remove it just by using the object I use on the parameter of the execute method, without generics.
Sorry my bad english, but I'll try to explain better.

Instead create my AsyncTask this way:

```
new AsyncTask<MyObject<GenericsInsideGenerics>, Void, Void>...
```

I've created this way:

```
new AsyncTask<MyObject, Void, Void>...
```

And it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the warning message then you have to use the designated varargs of AsyncTask.

```
private void tryNew(List<Something> somethingList){
    new AsyncTask<Something,Void,Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Something.. s) {
            //some code
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(somethingObject1, somethingObject2, somethingObject3);
}
```